# CKeditor with laravel encode output from database to raw html

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, ckeditor

I am building a simple blog but I would like to use the CKeditor for the blog message so users can style the blog message a little bit. I have never used CKeditor before and I am a bit new to Laravel also. So I managed to turn my textarea in a CKeditor field and I also build a function to store the blog posts. Thats not a problem, I see data in my database and also at my blog overview page.

But, CKeditor/Laravel will obviously store the tags, that are generated by CKeditor, in the database and will display them as just text. How can I display the text just like code?

Blog message now:

[image]

CKeditor

[image]

My code

Form

```
       <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="bericht">Nieuwsbericht <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="bericht" name="bericht" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'bericht' );
                </script>
```

Display a blog post

```
<div class="blog-post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h1>{{ $blog->name }}</h1>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h3>{{ $blog->subtitel }}</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="date">{{ $blog->created_at->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y') }}, Door {{$blog->user->name}}</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="blog-message">

                                    {{ $blog->bericht }}

                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `{{ $blog->bericht }}` try `{!! $blog->bericht !!}`

Info Here : https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-0-blade-changes

Comment: Nice! I already figured out I had to escape the data but didn't know how I would ever do that. Will accept your answer in 2 minutes :)

Comment: Glad to hear that .